# Pandas new set of columns from present set of column sliced by a categorical column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have table of form

| Bins | A_Color | B_Color | A_Size | B_Size. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 'Red' |  | 50 |  |
| B |  | 'Blue' |  | 60 |

and I wanted to have a common color and size columns instead of a set of columns for each category like this

| Bins | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 'Red' | 50 |
| B | 'Blue' | 60 |

I tried the below however got NaN values for ['Color', 'Size'] columns

```
bins = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    for b in bins:
        df.loc[df['Bins'] == b, ['Color', 'Size']] = \
            df.loc[df['Bins'] == b, [f'{b}_Color', f'{b}_Size']]
```

This is just an example, and the real data contains roughly 100K rows and more than 300+ columns.

Comment: What is number of rows in real data? There are only 5 bins in real data? Performance is important?

Comment: There are roughly 100K rows and more importantly 300+ columns

Comment: so bins has 150 values?

Comment: There are 6 categories and each category has 7 properties. Then there are other columns that are not related to this category

Comment: Then lookup solution in second answer should be fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html). You just have to rename your columns to match the format (A_Color -> Color_A)

```
>>> (pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1])), 
                     stubnames=['Color', 'Size'], i='Category', j='Cat', 
                     sep='_', suffix='\w+')
       .query('Category == Cat').droplevel('Cat').reset_index())

  Category Color  Size
0        A   Red  50.0
1        B  Blue  60.0
```

Details:

```
# Rename columns
>>> df1 = df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1]))
  Category Color_A Color_B  Size_A  Size_B  # <- HERE
0        A     Red     NaN    50.0     NaN
1        B     NaN    Blue     NaN    60.0

# Reshape dataframe
>>> out = pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames=['Color', 'Size'], i='Category', j='Cat', sep='_', suffix='\w+')
             Color  Size
Category Cat            
A        A     Red  50.0  # Keep
B        A     NaN   NaN  # Drop
A        B     NaN   NaN  # Drop
B        B    Blue  60.0  # Keep

# Filter rows
>>> out = out.query('Category == Cat')
             Color  Size
Category Cat            
A        A     Red  50.0
B        B    Blue  60.0

# Get final dataframe
>>> out = out.droplevel('Cat').reset_index()
  Category Color  Size
0        A   Red  50.0
1        B  Blue  60.0
```

Comment: Actual data has 340 columns. Would this still work?

Comment: I think so if all columns have the same format as your example.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is get first non missing value by splitted columns with `_`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Category')
         .groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1], axis=1)
         .first()
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Category Color  Size
0        A   Red  50.0
1        B  Blue  60.0
```

Solution with [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```
categories = ['Size','Color']

for c in categories:
    idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['Category'].add(f'_{c}'))
    df[c] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Your solution should be changed by converting to numpy array:

```
for b in bins:
    df.loc[df['Category'] == b, ['Color', 'Size']] = \
        df.loc[df['Category'] == b, [f'{b}_Color', f'{b}_Size']].to_numpy()
```